# How to expand pandas column containing values in arrays to multiple columns?

Tags: arrays, pandas, list, dataframe, mapping

I have a data frame with column named 'gear' which contains lists of values... what i want to do now is to move each element in every list to the corresponding column.
[image]

is there a way to do this without a need for a for loop?
for example in the first row the value 'Hengerfeste' in the list should be moved to 'Hengerfeste' column and so on for each element in the list.

Comment: Why don't you want a for loop?

Comment: it takes very long main problem with that are the multiple calls to .iloc to assign the values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `explode`, then `groupby().value_counts()`:

```
#sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[['a','b','c'], ['a','c','x'],[],['b','x','y']]})


(df['your_list_col'].explode()
   .groupby(level=0).value_counts()
   .unstack(fill_value=0)
   .reindex(df.index, fill_value=0)
)
```

Output:

```
col  a  b  c  x  y
0    1  1  1  0  0
1    1  0  1  1  0
2    0  0  0  0  0
3    0  1  0  1  1
```

Comment: man you are a genius! thanks this works!